# How to create an R object that includes space between characters in its name

Tags: r

I have a simple question which is if it is possible to create an object that includes space between letters in R. For example I want to create an object named "D B" with `DB<-c("a","b","c")`. Is it possible something like `D B<-c("a","b","c")` or should I create it as "DB" and the put space between letters in order to use it later as a dataframe column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
`D B` <- c("a", "b", "c")
```